# Launch pdf files from shell script

Tags: linux, windows, shell

script 1 - it generates pdf file into the path //c:/documents/xxxx

script 2 - launch pdf file generated by script 1 from Adobe Acrobat Reader.

I need a solution(i.e shell script) for script 2. Some one please advise me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Linux

`application name` `<filename>` should work. 
e.g. `evince myfile.pdf`

2. Windows

`START "" "path/to/file.pdf"`
This will open the file in the default application for PDF files.